# c# Regex match and replace using function

Tags: c#, regex

```
/// <summary>
/// Given HTML overlay for an image in the store, render it.
/// [p:n] renders as price for item ID n
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Rendered result</returns>
public static string RenderHTMLOverlay(string overlayHTML, int currencyID)
{
    const string pattern = "\\[p\\:(\\b\\d+\\b)\\]";
    overlayHTML = Regex.Replace(overlayHTML, pattern, FormatCurrency(GetItemPriceOnDate(DateTime.Now, currencyID, int.Parse("$1"))));

    return overlayHTML;
}
```

This doesn't work because `$1` can't be passed as a parameter correctly to `int.Parse`.

```
Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Does anyone know how I can work around this limitation?

Comment: Not related to the question, but I'd suggest using `@"\[p\:(\b\d+\b)\]"` instead if your expression for `pattern`.  Means the same thing and is more readable.

Comment: Even better: `@"\[p:(\d+)\]"`.  The colon doesn't need escaping and the word boundaries are redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the `$1` notation if the `replacement` argument is a string, so you ended up passing `$1` as a literal string to the `int.Parse` method.

Instead, use the [`(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) overload with an anonymous method:

```
Regex.Replace(overlayHTML, pattern, 
match => FormatCurrency(GetItemPriceOnDate(DateTime.Now, currencyID, int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value)))
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally sure I understand you, so bear with me if I am off.

```
 Console.WriteLine(int.Parse("$1"));  //throws exception Input string was not in a correct format.

 Console.WriteLine(int.Parse("$1".Replace("$", "")));  //Result: 1
```

If Store.CommonFunctions.GetItemPriceOnDate returns a string, you should be good to go.